# Data URI scheme and CORS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, cors

I think that data URI scheme is not a cross domain request, but I have found that firefox and chrome behave in a very different way.

I know doing this is a little weird. 
The question is not *why the hell want you ever to do a request on a data:text/json;, URI?*, but *would this be possible?*

http://jsfiddle.net/Zn4Rv/1/

```
$.get('data:text/json;,{"foo":"bar"}',function(data){
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

Firefox does, chrome doesn't.

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question in the last sentence of it.

Comment: I am wondering which one do the correct thing, Firefox or Chrome.


The data URI scheme definition RFC 2397 says nothing about.

Comment: AFAIK there is no published standard for the Same Origin Policy and browsers are free to determine their own rules.

Answer (score 1):

According to [The Web Origin Concept (RFC 6454)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454), a regular origin consists of the `triple (uri-scheme, uri-host, uri-port)`. Since the data URI scheme does not equal with the HTTP URI scheme, and the URI it describes certainly does not have the same host and port as your web application has, it is obvious that your data URI has a different origin.

### I created a sample code in php:

**http://test.loc/**
*Returns `aaa` in a HTTP response.*

```
aaa
```

**http://test.loc/x.html**
*Sends `GET http://test.loc/` and displays `aaa` in the body if not blocked by CORS.*

```
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "http://test.loc", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if (xhr.readyState==4)
        document.body.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
};
xhr.send();
</script>
```

**http://test.loc/y.php**
Loads the `http://test.loc/x.html` script from a data URI.

```
<object
    data="data:text/html;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents('x.html')); ?>"
></object>
```

### Results:

- msie does not support data URIs currently
- firefox always displays `aaa`
- chrome display `aaa` only if I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null`, otherwise it runs the script in a sandbox, and hides the XHR response from it

### Conclusion:

Currently only chrome supports CORS with data URIs in a proper way. We should send a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1016491) to mozilla, because this is a security issue. Javascript sent in a data URI can avoid regular js filters...

### After 3 years:

According to my bug report by Firefox, the specs are changed, so they fixed this. So data URIs require the allow origin header now on every browser where they are supported.

Comment: I read your mozilla issue, please give a link to the chrome issue you mentioned, as well as updating you answer.

Comment: @user2284570 What Chrome issue? Can you quote where I mentioned it?

Comment: [`Okay, I sent a bug report to them with a link to this report and a short description.`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1016491)

Comment: @user2284570 I checked my mails filtering "chromium" and "chrome", but did not find anything related this bug report. I assume I sent it, because I wrote so. Btw. I think it does not matter, I reported several bugs about browser inconsistency in the past years, but all of them failed because browser manufacturers do not want to communicate with each other and solve them. I think the fate of this report was just the same. I don't like developing for client side because of this attitude, and I try to avoid it if I can. Backend is much better. I might try WebGL on client side.

Comment: : This why technologies like java applets or flash player are so successful : same support and everywhere. Write your code once for all devices ;‑) .

Comment: @user2284570 I am not sure about that. E.g. silverlight was cool according to many programmer, but it was not successful.